# How to insert category list into post creation page, and retrieve chosen categories?

Tags: categories, loop, pages, templates, dashboard

I would like to display the full list of categories on the Page creation page, so that the user can pick using checkboxes which category posts should appear on that page.

[image: where I would like to display it]

I then need to retrieve the chosen categories for that specific page in my custom page templates, so that I can modify my loop to filter for only those chosen categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default page post type doesn't support category taxonomy. But you can easily fix it by register category taxonomy for page post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse8170_init' );
function wpse8170_init() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
}
```

Now you will see categories meta box in the same place as you see it at post creation page.

To get page's categories just call `wp_get_post_categories` function like this (thanks to @Subharanjan):

```
$page_categories = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID() );
```

Comment: How beautifully simple! how would I retrieve the chosen categories on their respective pages?

Comment: to be clear, I already have the code to loop through a selection of categories, I just need to retrieve the list of chosen categories to use as arguments in my existing loop.

Comment: @Kayo updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$page_categories = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID() );
```

Pass the current page id/ any pageid as the param and get the asociated categories.